# Creating Java Web service client in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, webservice-client

I have a Spring MVC application from which I am supposed to send a call to Soap web services. So for this reason, I created additional module inside my project following instructions on the *jetbrains* page (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/web-service-clients.html) and added support for GlassFish/JAXWS2.X RI/Netro 1.X/JWSDP2.0. Then I continued to follow instructions to generate Java code from wsdl(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html). The problem is it can't generate Java code and shows the following error.

```
[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL:      
http://link_to_web_services?wsdl. Failed to read the WSDL document: 
http://link_to_web_services?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is 
not <wsdl:definitions>.

[ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 
At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
Failed to parse the WSDL.`
```

I disabled proxy as well as manually set, none of them worked for me.

FYI, web services have been developed in IBM BUS Integration services and up and running.